# cmake with git for windows, MinGW and make

Tags: cmake, mingw

Firstly, I have installed MinGW from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ and the mingw32-gcc-g++ and mingw32-gcc-objs with it. I have added C:\MinGW\bin to my path.

Secondly, I have installed Git for windows (not really important, the result is the same on cmd.exe).

Thirdly, I have installed the complete package "make" with http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

After that, I have installed cmake 3.5.1 with the .msi.

But when I run `cmake ../src` the result is :

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/pauka/Dropbox/ETUDE/SRI/S8/STA_Stage/sources/tests/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/pauka/Dropbox/ETUDE/SRI/S8/STA_Stage/sources/tests/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So cmake can't find gcc or g++. But when I run gcc -version, the output is good... What should I configure for cmake ?

My CMakeLists.txt is :

```
# Ajustez en fonction de votre version de CMake
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

# Nom du projet
project (main)

find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Exécutable "main", compilé à partir du fichier main.cpp
add_executable (tracking_color tracking_color.cpp)
add_executable (feuille feuille.cpp)
add_executable (detect_circles detect_circles.cpp)
add_executable (segmentation segmentation.cpp)
add_executable (watershed_perso watershed_perso.cpp)
add_executable (main main.cpp utils.h)
add_executable (info_coins info_coins.cpp)

# main sera linké avec les bibliothèques d'OpenCV
target_link_libraries (tracking_color ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (feuille ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (detect_circles ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (segmentation ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (watershed_perso ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (info_coins ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Did you tell CMake that you wanted it to work in `make`/`gcc` mode and not VisualStudio mode? Does doing that help?

Comment: how do i do that ? When I run the cmake gui, I can configure, I tried "MSYS Makefiles", "Unix Makefiles" but the result is the same. Should I try another one ?

Comment: Well, you're not using MSYS make nor a Unix make. You're using the gnuwin32 make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, shame on me,

I had to restart my computer and select `"MinGW Makefiles"` in the CMake GUI. Click `Configure`, and after that `Generate`.

Next, you must not use `Git for windows` because there is `sh.exe` and it's a cmake bug.

PS: to use OpenCV, you must compile it :

```bash
cd C:\opencv
mkdir my_build
cd my_build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../sources
mingw32-make # took 2 hours on my computer
```

and next add, `C:\opencv\my_build` and `C:\opencv\my_build\bin` to the system path.

Comment: It took two hours because you didn't use the parallel build flag `-j` on make :')

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting [manually the cxx path](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables), see CMAKE_C_COMPILER from link which tells you more or less link this:

```
CXX=C:\path\to\g++ cmake ..
```

But, I would recommend you to see why cmake doesn't recognize your cxx compiler. I would double check your environment paths.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but get things going. Install `Bash On Ubuntu On Windows` and install cmake and make using `sudo apt-get install cmake` and `sudo apt-get install build-essential` if you don't already have them installed. However, `Bash On Ubuntu On Windows` only comes with `Windows 10` and for accessing a specific drive you should use `/mnt/c` instead of `C:\`

Follow [this official tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) to install `Bash On Ubuntu On Windows`.

```
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c$ cmake -version
cmake version 2.8.12.2
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c$ make -version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Additionally, of course you can install git in `Bash On Ubuntu On Windows`

```
sudo apt-get install git
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

though I don't suggest using a Linux-based git for pushing to github for a Windows specific SDK/code. I would still stick to Git Bash for dealing with git.

*I used to use CMAKE GUI for dealing with CMake in Windows 10 and then port my stuff to Visual Studio. That is also a neat solution depending on your codebase.